# Flowpaper PHP, not working on Ubuntu LTS 16.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, flexpaper

I have purchased the commercial zine package from flowpaper.com.
It works fine on windows 10
However on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, PHP package doesn't work. Even though  all the settings are correctly configured using setup.php page and the setup.php page shows success for all the configuration and binaries required for Ubuntu, the output is black browser screen.
All directories have proper permissions set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**pdf2swf** binary is not included in the swftools package for **Ubuntu 16.04**. I solved this issue by downloading the **swftools-0.9.2.tar.gz** package and manually compiling the binaries.

The documentation on flowpaper.com is outdated regarding linux install.